# resizing UIImage in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation

I have a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView and when the UIImageView frame size is bigger than the UIScrolLView size, I want to do an animation to shrink it back again to fit it in screen. However, doing the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
            [self.imageView_ setFrame:zoomedImageFrame];

        } completion:^(BOOL completed){
            //[self animateImageOnDismissal];
        }];
```

doesn't work, because I guess now the x and y origin offset is different, as it's shifted to the left. So how do I adjust it so that it zooms in/shrinks centered?

Comment: try to fix the center co-ordinates...

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to shrink the `UIImageView` that is larger than the content size of your `UIScrollView` to match it?  Upon the performing the above code, the `UIImageView` is shifted to the left? Secondly, where is zoomedImageFrame derived from?

Comment: yes...that is what I want.. zoomedImageFrame is actually the original frame before the content size of the UIImageView grows larger than the frame

Answer (score 0):

The following helps you to shrink the image.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
CGPoint center = imageView.center;

CGRect frame = imageView.frame;

frame.size.width = 100;
frame.size.height = 100;
imageView.frame = frame;
imageView.center = center;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here u can provide scrollView center to imageView, & also required width-height..